# DSUM with two conditions from an independent table with identical rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I have a form titled **"frm-SavedCancellations"** Access 2016 db with a Record Source titled "R-Totals" based on an independent table called **"tbl-Reserves"** The table has the following columns and SAMPLE ROW VALUES:

**COLUMN-A** =ABCDEFGHSDR **COLUMN-B** =B678 **COLUMN-AMT** =$100.00
**COLUMN-A** =ABCDEFGHSDR **COLUMN-B** =B765 **COLUMN-AMT** =$300.00
**COLUMN-A** =ABCDEFGHSDR **COLUMN-B** =B667 **COLUMN-AMT** =$300.00
**COLUMN-A** =RRRRRRRRR2 **COLUMN-B** =C6657 **COLUMN-AMT** =$25.00
**COLUMN-A** =RRRRRRRRR2 **COLUMN-B C7675** **COLUMN-AMT** =70.00

There are 5 rows, 3 matching COLUMN-A and COLUMN-AMT to be Summed while last 2 matching COLUMN-A to be SUMMED. Summed amounts must equal **$800 for the first 3 rows** and **$95 for the last two rows**    Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: What you want is not simple on a form if you want the dataset to be editable. This sort of data manipulation is what reports are for. On form, use an aggregate query (non-editable dataset) or DSum() with criteria to show the group total on each record line.

Comment: Strongly advise not to use punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Only exception is underscore.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes, you're correct it's not  simple, and already I have it in a report, but wanting the users to be able to edit the form "frm_SavedCancellations", and  have the "R_Total" control update from "tbl_Reserves". Again, Thanks.